# If n occurs less than 5 times, change to n-1

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, if I have a df of numbers c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5), how do change n to n-1 if n occurs less than 5 times? Example input x and output out.

```
    x out
1  1   1
2  1   1
3  1   1
4  2   1
5  3   3
6  3   3
7  3   3
8  3   3
9  3   3
10 3   3
11 4   3
12 4   3
13 4   3
```

As the first value in the column (it will also be the minimum value), 1 would stay the same. However, if it would make the coding easier, the 1s can change to 0, but the 2 would still change to 1.

**EDIT**: 
How can I repeat this if the changed values now occur <5 times? For example

```
#      x out
# [1,] 1   0
# [2,] 1   0
# [3,] 1   0
# [4,] 2   1
# [5,] 3   3
# [6,] 3   3
# [7,] 3   3
# [8,] 3   3
# [9,] 3   3
#[10,] 3   3
#[11,] 4   3
#[12,] 4   3
#[13,] 4   3
#[14,] 5   3
#[15,] 5   3
#[16,] 5   3
#[17,] 6   3
#[18,] 6   3
#[19,] 6   3
#[20,] 7   3
#[21,] 7   3
```

Comment: The 1s don't change because they are the lowest number (I don't want it to change to 0). As for the 5s, there was no subsequent data, so they didn't change either. But I edited the 5s in the question

Comment: As the first value in the row, 1 stays the same. If it would make the coding easier, it can change to 0, but the 2 would still change to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ave` :

```
x <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
pmax(x - +(ave(x, x, FUN =length) < 5), 1)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

If values in `x` can repeat we need to use `rle` for grouping.

```
pmax(x - +(ave(x,with(rle(x),rep(seq_along(values), lengths)),FUN =length) < 5),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rle` if x is sorted to find how many times a number is there. And subtract 1 if there are less then 5.

```
i <- order(x)
y <- rle(x[i])
y$values <- y$values - (y$lengths < 5)
cbind(x,out=inverse.rle(y)[order(i)])
#      x out
# [1,] 1   0
# [2,] 1   0
# [3,] 1   0
# [4,] 2   1
# [5,] 3   3
# [6,] 3   3
# [7,] 3   3
# [8,] 3   3
# [9,] 3   3
#[10,] 3   3
#[11,] 4   3
#[12,] 4   3
#[13,] 4   3
#[14,] 5   4
#[15,] 5   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
library(tidyvese)
x <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5)
df <- tibble(x = x)

df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  transmute(x, 
            out = if_else((x != min(x, na.rm = T) & n < 5), x - 1, x))
```